# node server.js gives error -> Cannot find module '../wireprotocol/2_4_support'

Tags: node.js, npm

To clarify the issue:

- I have built a node server, which works fine. But on pushing to git and cloning elsewhere, it doesn't work in the new location.
- Cleared node_modules, and tried npm install.
- gitignore has only node_modules directory in it.

package.json contains the following

```
{
  "name": "node-todo-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test || SET NODE_ENV=test && mocha server/**/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.2.2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.9",
    "validator": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
    "supertest": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you add the error statement then it will be easy for any one to ans.

Comment: Error is mentioned in the question: Cannot find module '../wireprotocol/2_4_support'

Comment: okay. in package.json no package like wireprotocol is present so try installing it separately by `npm install --save wire-protocol`  and then test if this work for you.

Comment: This didn't seem to work.